# css Grid grid-template-columns:

Tags: css, grid, css-grid

Why are this 4 columns? I mean when I use flexbox, we call it 4 rows. Now row becomes the column in CSS grid? Can you please explain?

Row is horizontal. I am using vs code on my pc

```
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

[image: img]

Comment: read about `grid-template-columns` ... by the way, you have 4 auto so the number 4 is somehow logical https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-columns

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Imagine there are 4  evenly spaced vertical lines on the page (the first and last lines represent the edges of the containing element).  *.item1* and *.item5* fall inside the first column, *.item2* and *.item6* inside the second, and so on.

You set 4 columns inside the *.grid-container* grid by repeating 'auto' four times in the 'grid-template-columns' property.  In other words, the number of columns in the grid is determined by the number of values set on the grid-template-columns property.

You can simplify this by using a new unit of measurement introduced by the grid system.  Suppose you want the second and fourth columns in your grid to be twice the size of the first and third.  You can simply declare the following:

```
grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr 1fr 2fr;
```

The fractionals indicate how much space each column will use relative to the size and number of the other columns.

To set the size and number of rows within the grid, use "grid-template-rows"

For both properties, you may also pass in a 'repeat' function as a value:

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr)
```

This is equivalent to setting "1fr 1fr 1fr" on the grid container.

Comment: **I_got_it** @Eric R.